# Check whether a number can be expressed as sum of x powers of two

Tags: math, binary, bit-manipulation

Is there a bit trick to check whether a number can be expressed as sum of x powers of 2?

Example: For x=3 n=21, the numbers are 16, 4, and 1. If n=30, it should be false, because there are no 3 powers of two to represent 30.

Comment: If all the powers of 2 must be different, then n is a sum of x powers of 2 iff there are x set bits in the binary expansion of n.

Comment: what if they don't have to be different ?

Comment: Your question appears to be about maths rather than programming; you might get better answers at a maths site rather than a programming one. I think my comment could be taken further: if there are more than x set bits in the binary expansion or n, then n cannot be expressed as a sum of x powers or 2, even if they are allowed to be the same. On the other hand, if for example n = 9 = 2^3 + 2^0 (two set bits) we could write this as 2^2 + 2^2 + 2^0 as required. Good luck.

Comment: thanks that really helped after some experiments i found that the least x should be the number of set bits if there are less than that it cannot be and the max x should the number of bits wheather it's set or unset because you always can add 2^0 as much as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number n …

- … the minimum x is the number of `1`-bits in n. This number is called popcount(n).
  Example: The binary number `0b1011` needs at least popcount(`0b1011`)=3 powers of two to be summed up (`0b1000`+`0b0010`+`0b0001`).
- … the maximum x is n. Because `1` is a power of two you can add `1` n times to get n.

Now comes the hard question. What if x is between popcount(n) and n?
As it turns out, all of these x are possible. To build a sum of x powers of two …

- start at the shortest sum (the binary representation of n)
- If you have less than x addends, split any addend that is bigger than 1 into two addends, increasing the number of addends by one. This can be done until you arrive at x=n.

#### Example: Can 11=`0b1011` be expressed as a sum of x=7 powers of two?

Yes, because popcount(n)=3 <= x=7 <= n=11.

To build a sum with x=7 powers of two we use
11 = `0b1011` = `0b1000`+`0b10`+`0b1` | only 3 addends, so split one
= (`0b100`+`0b100`)+`0b10`+`0b1` | only 4 addends, so split another one
= ((`0b10`+`0b10`)+`0b100`)+`0b10`+`0b1` | only 5 addends, so split another one
= (((`0b1`+`0b1`)+`0b10`)+`0b100`)+`0b10`+`0b1` | only 6 addends, so split another one
= (((`0b1`+`0b1`)+(`0b1`+`0b1`))+`0b100`)+`0b10`+`0b1` | 7 addends, done

#### Implementation

To implement the check *»can n can be expressed as sum of x powers of two?«* use

```
isSumOfXPowersOfTwo(n, x) {
   return x<=n && x>=popcount(n).
}
```

For efficient bit-twiddling implementations of `popcount` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/6770384). Some processors even have an instruction for that.